# Most popular packages/stacks

Tags: ros, stacks, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I discovered the MoveIt and navigation packages that are really awesome, and I would like to know if there's a listing somewhere with the other packages that are as huge.

I know there's a wiki page with ALL the packages/metapackages/stacks, but the list is really huge and there are a lot of small packages, so if anybody has a list containing the ones that should not be missed, it would be really helpful for beginners like me :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207267/most-popular-packages/stacks/) by [LiohAu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22186/liohau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2015-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have a list but some packages are:

1. OpenCv - for vision
2. gmapping and openslam_gmapping - evident from the names
3. PCL with ROS

---

Originally posted by [p_mukherjee](https://answers.ros.org/users/22619/p_mukherjee/) with karma: 16 on 2015-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0